# How does a body know where it has min/max energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, potential-energy, equilibrium

So today I was learning about equilibrium and I got to know that a body moves away from an unstable equilibrium because its potential energy at the unstable equilibrium is high. For example, in a pendulum the bob moves towards its central position because at the center its potential energy is minimal, but the bob moves towards the center because the direction of net forces on the bob is towards the center and therefore—even if there had not been an equilibrium—the bob would have moved there due to the net forces acting in that direction.

So how does equilibrium affect its position? And how does the bob know that at the center it will have minimal potential energy?

Comment: Wait until you learn about "Action". It's basically the same thing but with paths instead of position. It's even weirder about "how it knows" all possible paths ahead of time and is able to pick which one has the last action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For eg in Pendulum the Bob moves towards its center position because at center it's Potential energy is min but the Bob moves towards the center because the direction of net force on Bob is towards center and therefore even if there had not been an equilibrium, the Bob would have moved there due to net force acting in that direction

Actually, the force is a result of a "slope" in the potential energy, as can be seen in the equation relating the two:
$$
F = - \nabla U \text{.}
$$
So, you can think of equilibrium as a point where the net force is zero. (But remember that the above relation only holds for conservative forces - in the case of a pendulum, the force is gravitational, so it is conservative.)

Forces are a useful concept in some situations so that you can visualise how different bodies interact, and you can link particular movements to their causes, i.e., the forces that cause them. Although in classical mechanics one may argue that forces can be treated fundamentally, in general they are just a description of interactions between matter and fields. In the case of a pendulum, the bob wants to minimise its potential energy. However, as it goes down the "slope" of potential energy, it gains kinetic energy, and thus keeps moving even after passing the equilibrium point, returning to the same state, and so on and so forth. Of course, the bob itself does not know its energy but it just follows the path according to the laws of physics. By saying that "it wants to minimise its energy" we allude to these laws in order to understand more easily the reasoning behind the path it is taking.

The reason why we like to use potential energy instead of forces in physics is that forces are a sensible concept only in classical mechanics. For instance, in quantum mechanics it's not possible to distinguish forces acting on a particle, and thus we use other formalisms to be able to derive equations of motion. Even in classical mechanics, there are problems which are way easier if you leave forces behind - e.g., a double pendulum - try to solve that in Newtonian mechanics and you will see it's tedious. If you would use the Lagrangian formalism of classical mechanics, which uses potential energy instead of forces, it would be easier, but that you will probably learn in the near future, after you complete your introductory mechanics course.

I hope I managed to clear up at least some of your doubts. If you want to know more about what makes different formalisms equivalent, google the principle of least action. But don't worry if you do not understand the concept yet - you'll also be learning it in later mechanics courses.

Comment: This is a good answer! The relation between potential energy and force $F = - \nabla U \text{.}$ is the short and perfect answer for OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If we treat the system as *frictionless*, motion is perpetual as the pendulum passes the equilibrium point with the same amount of momentum every time. True systems are *thermodynamic* and tend to dissipate their kinetic energy into internal energy. The result is that each subsequent time the pendulum passes the point of zero net force it moves a little slower than the time before. As this continuous to happen, the pendulum eventually stops. The resting point is the point of zero force, which defines the equilibrium point.

While it is a bit dangerous to talk about what the pendulum "knows" or "doesn't know" as it moves, it would be accurate to say that it does not actively seek the position of lowest energy but merely responds to force. *We* (the observer) define potential energy in such way that the point of zero force corresponds to its minimum.

Comment: If universe expands then its entropy increases. So the amount of heat to do same work also increases. Now from where this extra heat needed to do same work. Is it friction, no it is entropy. So there is no perpetual motion, because very concept of motion is to increase volume.

Answer (score -3):

As Aristotle said, nature of motion is to rest. So peundulum's bob tries to keep its energy minimum in absence of external energy, it remain there. This is case of restoring force or potential energy, it tries to keep its potential energy minimum. The change in energy is deflection from its mean or rest position, so its energy changes with change in angular displacement, $\theta$.

Its potential energy at any value of angle is given by, $E=mgl(1-\cos \theta)$. Now minima of potential energy is differential of it with angular distance equals $0$, $$\frac{dE}{d\theta}=mgl\sin \theta=0$$
Now $m$ is constant, $g$ is constant and $l$ is constant, so only $\sin \theta$ can be $0$ for $\theta=0$ or $\pi$. Thus potential energy can be minimum at angular displacement of $0$ or $\pi$. But at $\pi$, $E$ is maximum. Thus bob have minimum potential energy at its mean position.

Comment: Obligatory -1 for basing your explanation on *Aristotle's* understanding of mechanics, the refutation of which corresponds to the birth of physics as we know it.

Comment: Thanks for telling. But Aristotle view was realistic while Galilean was idealistic. By applying constant smaller force, one can't achieve higher speed or constant acceleration because limited force produce limited speed. No this is not relativistic because we saw it in Planck's law, finite temperature produce finite power.

Comment: @J.Murray Obviously, Neil's explanation is *not* based on Aristotle. My reading of Aristotle's quote is that he anticipated *thermodynamics* (dissipation) centuries before Carnot.

Comment: @Themis The first sentence of this answer (assuming that it means to say that *the natural state of motion of an object is rest*) is unambiguously wrong, and has been known to be unambiguously wrong for many centuries. The fact that dissipative forces tend to bring objects to rest gives the wrong intuition here, because in the model of an ideal pendulum there is no dissipation. The pendulum bob does *not* try to minimize its energy by remaining motionless.

Comment: @J.Murray I don’t understand: the ideal pendulum does not minimize its potential energy, it just oscillates from its minimum to some maximum and back. But there are no ideal pendulums in this universe. All real  pendulums eventually rest at the point of minimum potential energy.

Comment: @Themis The question is how the restoring force (in this case, the tangential component of the gravitational force) knows to push the pendulum bob back toward the (stable) equilibrium point. The answer is essentially that we *define* the potential energy $U$ such that the corresponding force is in the direction of decreasing $U$ - that is, toward the nearest local minimum. This has nothing whatsoever to do with dissipation, and certainly nothing to do with Aristotle's belief that the pendulum endeavors to remain at rest.

Comment: @J.Murray That is what I said that Galilean view is idealistic that a body remain in its state of motion. This brought concept of acceleration by external force. But a body subjected to constant force can't gain infinite speed. This is similar in a body producing radiation where there is no friction, it is entropy. Now definition of mass is inertia to change in motion, but there is no friction in space. So this definition becomes invalid or a body gains infinite speed. This was tried to corrected by relativity, but that assumes two assumptions that constancy and limit of light's speed.

Comment: @J.Murray We don't define potential, it comes out naturally and it cause restoring force that produces oscillation. Without potential, pendulum is simple case of f=ma and s=at². By the way, area under curve of Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of speed gives maximum limit of speed obtained by particles subjected to temperature. Increase the temperature, increases speed, and this without friction. What is inside an atom, still an excited atom comes to ground state in nanoseconds. Pendulum was at rest, momentarily force cause motion, but pendulum eventually comes to rest, this is Aristotelian view.